# create a complex variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, variables, select

I have a problem with MySQL syntax.  I have generated a table with real airplane flights and imaginary airplane flights:

```
Flight_ID   Imaginary
12345678       0
12345678       1
12345678       1
12345678       1
23456789       0
23456789       1
23456789       1
etc......
```

Imaginary flights have the same `Flight_ID` as the real flight from which they were generated.  The `Imaginary` column indicates if its a real `0` or imaginary `1` flight.

I need to CREATE a new variable called `Type` that will indicate if it's a real flight, or option1, option2, option3......

I can't find the right syntax to create these option1, option2, option3 modalitites.

Comment: What are option1, option2, option3?

Comment: option1, option2, etc are the modalities of my new variable Type, option1=first imaginary flight, option2=second imaginary flight, etc

Comment: why not using int value and counting 0,1,2,... 0 is real, all others are imaginary with rank

Comment: how can i do that? put 0 for real flight, 1,2,3.... for imaginary? so it will make smth like this 0,1,2,3,4, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 0,1,2 etc?

Comment: How does one distinguish between the options?  Or, to put it another way, how does one determine which option should be which?  Or does it not matter: in which case, why number them at all?

Comment: it doesnt matter which option has which number, i need it to know how many imaginary flights has each real flight, this has to be in table for statistic analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Flight_ID, Imaginary, IF(Imaginary=0, @img:=0, TRUE) ignoreThisCol, 
       IF(Imaginary=0, 'real flight', CONCAT('option',  @img:=@img+1)) flightType , 
       IF(Imaginary=0, @curFlight:=Flight_ID, TRUE) ignoreThisCol
FROM flights, (SELECT @curFlight:=0, @img:=0) a
ORDER BY Flight_ID, Imaginary
```

Comment: it's almost worked out, except that it putted only option0. It looks like this: Flight_ID / Imaginary/ Flight_type
           12345678     0         Real flight
           12345678     1         option0
           12345678     1         option0
           12345678     1         option0
           23456789     0         Real flight
           23456789     1         option0
           23456789     1         option0

Comment: What have you changed in query?

Comment: just the name of the table flights --> final